# Python graph structure and surprising list handling

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm implementing a graph structure (just for practicing purposes) and now I came to two behaviors I cannot explain to myself.

first, here the code

```
class Node:
    data = None
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

class GraphNode(Node):
    children = []
    def __init__(self, list_of_nodes=None, data=None):
        if list_of_nodes != None:
            for node in list_of_nodes:
                children.add(node)
        self.data = data

def createGraphStructure():
    node1 = GraphNode(data=1)
    node2 = GraphNode(data=2)
    node3 = GraphNode(data=3)
    node4 = GraphNode(data=4)
    node5 = GraphNode(data=5)
    node6 = GraphNode(data=6)
    node7 = GraphNode(data=7)
    node8 = GraphNode(data=8)

    node1.children.append([node2, node3, node4])
    node2.children.append([node5, node6, node7])
    node4.children.append([node8])

    #just a random test/visualization
    print node1.children
    #another random printout to test/visualize
    for n in node1.children:
        print n.data

    return node1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = createGraphStructure()
    #do stuff with graph, bfs dfs whatever
```

Now first surprising thing: 
`print node1.children` in `createGraphStructure()` will print out the following: `[[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8]]`, but i expected it only to print out the immediate children of node 1, like `[2, 3, 4]`. I am completely clueless here.

Secondly, the part

```
for n in node1.children:
    print n.data
```

throws following exception:

```
File "C:/yeah/you/would/like/to/see/my/path/right?/datastructures.py", line 54, in createGraphStructure
    print n.data
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'
```

As it seems, `n` is a list, but why? Shouldnt it be a node from the list?
Im sure there are some obvious explanations for that but I cant figure them out. Also because im not too proficient with Python, especially not OO.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, when you do this:

```
class GraphNode(Node):
    children = []
```

`children` here is *class* data, not *instance* data. That is, *all* of your nodes are sharing the same `children` object, so each of the `append` calls is actually changing the same variable.

To have instance data, you need to create `children` in a method so that it can access a reference to an instance. Typically, this is done in `__init__`:

```
class GraphNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, list_of_nodes=None, data=None):
        self.children = []  # <-- initialised here
        if list_of_nodes != None:
            for node in list_of_nodes:
                children.add(node)
        self.data = data
```

The second problem, is that you've used `append` where it appears that you meant to use `extend`.

`append` takes an object, and adds this object to a list:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.append([4, 5, 6])
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

See here, the fourth item in the list is another list. Instead, use `extend`, which takes a list, and concatenates it with the list it is called on:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.extend([4, 5, 6])
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```